# What algorithm is fast and good (optimized) for comparing candidates?

Tags: algorithm, function, sorting, vim, compare

I'm using Vim plugin `neocomplcache`. And I hope a better compare_func for neocomplcache's popup menu candidates.

You can find the default `compare_func` at [here](https://github.com/Shougo/neocomplcache/blob/master/autoload/neocomplcache.vim#L1248).

And here is the [issue](https://github.com/Shougo/neocomplcache/issues/305) I post on GitHub.

Reference:

- [neocomplcache](https://github.com/Shougo/neocomplcache)

I'm still newbie on programming, I'm not good on algorithm, basiclly totally do not know the algorithm.
Anyway, I want to know what algorithm or ways is good for this case.
And thanks.

Comment: You want the StackOverflow community to solve a perceived optimization issue that the plugin's author has no interest in tackling?

Comment: I just ask is there some way or algorithm for this compare sort. No other means.

Comment: @IngoKarkat - lol, you are essentially right but I for one am curious for what the community can come up with. The plugin itself might be worth trying to.

Comment: And I think this compare function which `connect10` is up of `connect2` can be better.

Comment: @NagatoPain - You are asking for a natural sort but that is quit hard to get right. At the moment, all you care about is that 10 should come after 2 but the next user will expect é to be equal to e...

Comment: @Lieven "natural sort" ? any other suggestions? I will wiki it by myself.

Comment: [This](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/12/sorting-for-humans-natural-sort-order.html) is one article about natural sort I once read about *(and it pops up as first hit when searching on Google)*.